# Join row contents element-wise in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Sometimes my csv's have more than one header row, all of which are important. For instance, the second header row might contain the scientific unit of the values in the column. I need to combine the header rows into one header row so that I can do operations and plots on the numerical data. I want to be able to do this for the first n lines in the csv, or rows in the dataframe, where I specify n.

[image]

Alternate suggestions on how to deal with this problem welcome. Editing each csv is not viable. pandas beginner here, but not new to programming.

Comment: Honestly, I would read the `csv` twice, the first just 2 rows, then the second to get all of the data. With the above everything is `object` so you have to then convert all of the datatypes appropriately, instead of letting `pandas` do that automatically.

Comment: Can you post the first few lines of the csv as formatted text (in a code block) instead of the above image?

Comment: as someone who routinely cleans messy SAP data which comes with n number of header rows mostly crosstabs, I agree with ALollz, read in the df twice or slice it using `.loc` or `.iloc` to wrangle your headers.

Comment: We can read file once, loop it for n rows, concat individual row per column and store in new data frame, populate rest of file data in dataframe as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually handle data like this as follows :

just creating some dummy data for you, please prepare this for SO in future, it really helps others answer your question easily. (also incase anyone has a better answer)!

```
pore_throat = ['(nm)',21638,20542,19431.2,18262.85]
injection_pres = ['(psi)',4.93,5.19,5.49,5.82]
df = pd.DataFrame({'pore throat radius' : pore_throat,
             'Injection Pressure' : injection_pres})
```

assuming your data is called file:

```
df_cols = pd.read_csv(file,nrows=1)

cols = df_cols.columns + ' ' + df_cols.iloc[0]
df = pd.read_csv(file,skiprows=1) # skip the string row so the dtypes are numbers/floats.
df.columns = cols
print(df)
pore throat radius (nm)     Injection Pressure (psi)
1   21638.00    4.93
2   20542.00    5.19
3   19431.20    5.49
4   18262.85    5.82
```